# What is the meaning of white noise in AR model?

Tags: time-series, autoregressive, white-noise

I am new to Time Series. I want to know the meaning of white noise.
By definition it is given that

> $w_t\stackrel{_{_\text{iid}}}{\sim} N(0,σ^2_w)$, meaning that the errors are independently distributed with a normal distribution that has mean $0$ and constant variance.

What does it actually mean?Can someone explain with example?
And how by adding this with previous time value gives current time value as in the equation below?

> $x(t)=δ + ϕ \cdot x(t−1) + w_t$

Comment: 1. What are you quoting there? 2. GIven you have a definition there in your question, what do you mean by "meaning"? Is part of the definition unclear, or are you seeking some other kind of explanation (and if so, what is it you need)?

Comment: I want to know how we get above mentioned equation,and why white noise came into that equation.

Comment: The AR(1) equation is simply definition, it's not derived from anything else. The current observation is linear in the previous observation plus white noise.